# Calculating hitting time of state $m$ given starting in state $i$ on an asymmetric random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: recurrence-relations, markov-chains, random-walk

Consider a Simple Random Walk, $(X_n)_n≥0$, on $\mathbb{Z}$ where we have the following:

$    P_{ij} =
\begin{cases}
p&\text{if i = j + 1}\\
q=1-p&\text{if i = j - 1}\\
0&\text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}
$

Suppose that $1 > p > q > 0$. We know that the process $(X_n)_{n≥0}$ is transient for all states $i ∈ Z$.

**QUESTION:** For state $m ∈ I$, let $H^m := inf\{n ≥ 0 : X_n = m\}$. Suppose that $m < 0$. Then
show that for $m < i ∈ I$
$$h_i:= P_i(H^m < ∞) = a^{f(i,m)}$$ where $a$ is a constant and $f(i, m)$ is a function of $i$ and $m$.

**So far I have:** I have looked around on here and through other resources and I can't find anything to help me solve this question rigorously. I have thought about this problem and as
$$h_i = ph_{i+1} + qh_{i-1}. $$
This recurrence relation with assuming $h_i = \lambda^i$ produces a solution of the form
$$ h_i = A + B(\frac{q}{p})^i$$

As $h_m$ is the probability of hitting state $m$ given we start at $m$, I have concluded that $h_m = 1$.

However, I am having trouble coming up with a second boundary condition to solve for A and B. Any help would be appreciated. As q < p, this is an asymmetric random walk on Z. *Please note the state space is all of the integers and that* $m < i$ *and* $m < 0$.

I believe as q < p this leads to $h_i = (\frac{q}{p})^{i-m}$ but I cannot get there.